# php decode json array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have a php page that receives a json object from javascript page, but i was not able to decode the json in php. How to decode the json and store in php such that $arr[0]=[1,2,34,5,2]; $arr[1]=[2,1,34,5,2]; $arr[2]=[8,1,34,5,2]; in php ?

```
after removing "myString = JSON.stringify(myObject);"
echo $value; outputs "Array"
echo $value[0]; outputs nothing
echo $value->{"key"};  outputs nothing either

how can i actually get the array contents?
```

javascript:

```
var mon=[1,2,34,5,2];
var tue=[2,1,34,5,2];
var wed=[8,1,34,5,2];
var myObject = {'key' :'value','key2':'value','key3':'value'};

myObject.key = mon;
myObject.key2 = tue;
myObject.key3 = wed;

 myString = JSON.stringify(myObject); //this line removed

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(myObject);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "n3.php",
    data: {data : jsonString}, 
    cache: false,

    success: function(aaa){ 
        alert("OK");

         $("#pageContent").html(aaa);       
    }
});
```

php:

```
<?php
$value = json_decode($_POST['data']);
echo $value;     //this echos the whole json object 
echo $value->{"key"};  //this outputs nothing
?>
```

Comment: Can you post what does `echo $value;` gives?

Comment: now echo $value; gives "Array", how can i get the array content?

Comment: Try `var_dump($value)`.

Comment: i dont want to just output the array, i want to store it into php variables so that $arr[0]=[1,2,34,5,2]; $arr[1]=[2,1,34,5,2]; $arr[2]=[8,1,34,5,2]; anyway i can do that?

Comment: \*cough\*cough\* Try `var_dump($value)` **to see what you have and what you're trying to work with.** \*cough\*cough\*

Comment: var_dump($value) gives the following :    array(3) { ["key"]=> array(11) { [0]=> int(12) [1]=> int(13) [2]=> int(9) [3]=> int(12) [4]=> int(13) [5]=> int(1) [6]=> int(2) [7]=> int(5) [8]=> int(8) [9]=> int(9) [10]=> int(10) } ["key2"]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(9) [1]=> int(13) [2]=> int(14) [3]=> int(15) } ["key3"]=> array(5) { [0]=> int(12) [1]=> int(13) [2]=> int(11) [3]=> int(12) [4]=> int(17) } }

Comment: So, `$value['key'][0]` it is.

Answer (score 2):

You are JSON encoding your data twice on the Javascript side. When you call `json_encode` in PHP once, you get a JSON encoded object back. That's why `echo $value` outputs the whole string. If it was a PHP array at this point it would output "Array" or an error in case it was an object, it would not output the whole content.

Either `json_decode` it again, or don't double encode it in Javascript.